# I need co-occurrence dataframe of characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, embedding

```
import pandas as pd

corpus = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'A B C A D B A'], [2, 'B A B B C B A']], columns=['id',
                      'sequence'])
corpus
```

Expected Output

```
    A B C D
1   3 2 1 1
2   2 4 1 0
```

I have a dataframe that looks like above. I need to count co-occurrence of each character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `split` then `explode` and `str.get_dummies`

```
out = corpus.set_index('id').sequence.str.split(' ').explode().str.get_dummies().groupby(level=0).sum()
   A  B  C  D
1  3  2  1  1
2  2  4  1  0
```

Answer (score 3):

You could `split` the string, `explode`, and count the values per group:

```
(corpus.set_index('id')['sequence']
       .str.split(' ')
       .explode()
       .groupby(level='id').value_counts()
       .unstack(level='sequence', fill_value=0)
)
```

output:

```
sequence  A  B  C  D
id                  
1         3  2  1  1
2         2  4  1  0
```